# Blender behaves like it applies boolean tool after each manipulation

Tags: edit-mode

I opened another person's .blend file and can't get rid of this annoying problem that drives me insane. Every time I manipulate geometry in edit mode, it would add vertices at intersections as if I were applying the intersect knife tool after every step. Here's example of what's happening, before I move any vertices: [image: initial image]

And after:

[image]

I tried to search for it, but didn't find anything related, most probably because this "auto knife mode" is called somewhat different. It's extremelly frustrating and doesn't suite my geometry optimization task at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have these options enabled:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! You have no idea how much nuisance it was trying to Google up what it is.